Replacing the motor in my 2007 Chevy Suburban LTZ
I'm having the hardest time located a block for my 2007 Chevy Suburban LTZ with 3 as the 8th digit in my vin.
It's a flex fuel system, can anyone point me in the direction of any places that might have any 5.3L flex fuel engines or complete blocks?
Or give me the run down on what changes or modifications I should make to just convert it to a regular gasoline engine?
